# Does an adapter exist that can convert a rotary tool in a oscillating multi-tool one?

Tags: tools, powertools, grinder

I saw in the Internet a power tool with a proprietary attachment system that can transform the power base in a drill, in a cutter, in a jig saw, in a multi-too and so on... more than 10 different tools.

Is it possible to convert the rotary motion of a normal angle grinder to an oscillationg motion of a multi-tool? Does a similar universal adapter exists?

Comment: I don't believe there are any good options for this. I have found with experience that a tool specifically designed for the job works much better and is more reliable than one of these multi-tools. A good quality oscillating tool may be well within your budget. They are pretty reasonable. I recently bought a higher end oscillating tool, and it cuts through wood like butter. Even the one I purchased was quite reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

There are no universal solutions.  All the powerheads are proprietary (as are the batteries/chargers)

An angle grinder is too fast, too heavy and too powerful for the precision that the oscillators provide, as a class.

Any combo you would jury rig in this fashion would not be worth the time, money and frustration.

I have the Rigid oscillator, and I think it's a bit heavy, vs the Fein single function, but I like the right angle impact driver for close quarters use

Good luck if you invent something, let us know.